# Laplace transform of $\cos^2(\omega t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

Find the Laplace Transform of $\cos^2(\omega t)$, where $\omega$ is a constant.

From a cosine identity: $cos^2(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2\omega t))$.

So then I get:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(\cos^2(\omega t)) & = \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}(1+\cos(2\omega t))\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{L}(1) + \mathcal{L}(\cos(2\omega t)))\\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{s} + \mathcal{L}(\cos(2\omega t))\right)
\end{align}

This is the part where I'm unsure how to proceed. Can I use the fact that $\mathcal{L}(\cos(\omega t)) = \frac{s}{s^2+\omega^2}$ to get $\mathcal{L}(\cos(2\omega t)) = \frac{s}{s^2 + (2 \omega)^2}$ or do I have to use the definition of Laplace transformation and do the integration to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is OK, you get
$$
\mathcal{L}(\cos^2(\omega t))=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{s} + \mathcal{L}(\cos(2\omega t))\right)=\frac{1}{2 s}+\frac{s}{2 \left(s^2+4 w^2\right)}
$$ where we have used

> $$\mathcal{L}(\cos\omega t) = \frac{s}{s^2 + \omega^2}.$$

Comment: This only works because we know that $\omega$ is a constant right?

Comment: @user3370201 Yes, exactly.